# How can I reduce the gap or even resize my panel containing of JLabels to reduce the vertical space?

Tags: java, swing

[image: GUI with broken layout]

I added an etched to see the amount of space the first panel takes up. My `mainPanel` uses `BorderLayout`. In its center I added a panel that uses `BoxLayout`. Inside the `BoxLayout` I stacked multiple `FlowLayout`s for each row.

```java
JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Show Citizens");
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JLabel header = new JLabel("SHOW CITIZENS BASED ON FILTERS");
header.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
header.setOpaque(true);
header.setBackground(Color.decode("#728FCE"));
header.setForeground(Color.decode("#F5F5F5"));
header.setFont(new Font("Dublin", Font.BOLD, 20));
mainPanel.add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
JLabel footer = new JLabel("CITIZENS' DATABASE ANALYSIS");
footer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
footer.setOpaque(true);
footer.setBackground(Color.decode("#728FCE"));
footer.setForeground(Color.decode("#F5F5F5"));
footer.setFont(new Font("Dublin", Font.BOLD, 20));
mainPanel.add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
JPanel center = new JPanel();
center.setLayout(new BoxLayout(center, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JLabel filterLabel = new JLabel("FILTERS");
filterLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
filterLabel.setFont(new Font("Dublin", Font.BOLD, 20));
filterLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
center.add(filterLabel);
center.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
JPanel filterLabelsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,100,0));
filterLabelsPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
filterLabelsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
JLabel districtLabel = new JLabel("DISTRICTS");
districtLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
districtLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
districtLabel.setFont(new Font("Dublin", Font.PLAIN, 14));
districtLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,15));
filterLabelsPanel.add(districtLabel);
JLabel residentLabel = new JLabel("RESIDENCY");
residentLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
residentLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
residentLabel.setFont(new Font("Dublin", Font.PLAIN, 14));
residentLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,15));
filterLabelsPanel.add(residentLabel);
JLabel sexLabel = new JLabel("SEX");
sexLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
sexLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
sexLabel.setFont(new Font("Dublin", Font.PLAIN, 14));
sexLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,15));
filterLabelsPanel.add(sexLabel);
JPanel filterChoicePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 100,0));
filterChoicePanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
Integer[] districtList = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
JComboBox district = new JComboBox(districtList);
district.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
filterChoicePanel.add(district);
String[] residencyList = {"Resident", "Non-Resident"};
JComboBox residency = new JComboBox(residencyList);
residency.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
filterChoicePanel.add(residency);
String[] sexList = {"Male", "Female"};
JComboBox sex = new JComboBox(sexList);
sex.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
filterChoicePanel.add(sex);
center.add(filterLabelsPanel);
center.add(filterChoicePanel);
mainPanel.add(center);
mainFrame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
mainFrame.setSize(900,600);
mainFrame.setVisible(true);
mainFrame.setResizable(false);
mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

I tried to create a border around it but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: What do you want to do with the space? You're setting the size of the JFrame manually, so what should happen to the layout? Maybe you could create a version of the image with the layout you want?

Comment: I understand that you posted an image of how your GUI actually looks and you don't want it to look like that. So can you post an image of how you want it to look?

Comment: don't hard-code sizing hints

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Comment: @kleopatra isn't setting the size of the window necessary sometimes? For example if keeping preferences from a previous program run?

Comment: ... or maybe you mean the 'setPreferredSize' and such?

Comment: @matt meant min/pref/max (of contained components), indeed :) top-level containers are a different story, slightly

Comment: @kleopatra what do you think about starting a canonical question for this. Where the answers are some various pitfalls. eg. A gui where in one LAF/DPI it looks desired, but in another you cannot read any of the buttons.

Comment: @matt that would be yet another resource that askers don't read ;) There's already the api doc, the excellent oracle doc (yeah, at that time Sun invested in writing such), enough QAs here to study ..

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted was a confusing mess.  Java has methods, which can be used to break up your code into bite-size pieces that you can experiment with and test with different Swing layout managers.

Here's the GUI I came up with.

[image: Example]

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I created separate `JPanels` for the header, middle, and footers.  The header and footer `JPanels` both used a `FlowLayout`.

For the middle `JPanel`, I used a `GridBagLayout`.  Any time you're creating a "form-like" structure, think `GridBagLayout`.

A `GridBagLayout` `JPanel` would center itself in the middle both horizontally and vertically.  To move the Swing components to the top, I enclosed the `GridBagLayout` `JPanel` in a `FlowLayout` `JPanel`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ShowCitizensExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ShowCitizensExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Show Citizens");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainFrame.add(createTitlePanel("SHOW CITIZENS BASED ON FILTERS"),
                BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainFrame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainFrame.add(createTitlePanel("CITIZENS' DATABASE ANALYSIS"),
                BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainFrame.setSize(900, 600);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTitlePanel(String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.decode("#728FCE"));

        JLabel header = new JLabel(text);
        header.setBackground(Color.decode("#728FCE"));
        header.setForeground(Color.decode("#F5F5F5"));
        header.setFont(new Font("Dublin", Font.BOLD, 20));
        panel.add(header);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Font labelFont = new Font("Dublin", Font.PLAIN, 14);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 100, 10, 100);

        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel filterLabel = new JLabel("FILTERS");
        filterLabel.setFont(new Font("Dublin", Font.BOLD, 20));
        panel.add(filterLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel districtLabel = new JLabel("DISTRICTS");
        districtLabel.setFont(labelFont);
        panel.add(districtLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        JLabel residentLabel = new JLabel("RESIDENCY");
        residentLabel.setFont(labelFont);
        panel.add(residentLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        JLabel sexLabel = new JLabel("SEX");
        sexLabel.setFont(labelFont);
        panel.add(sexLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        Integer[] districtList = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
                14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
        JComboBox<Integer> district = new JComboBox<>(districtList);
        panel.add(district, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        String[] residencyList = { "Resident", "Non-Resident" };
        JComboBox<String> residency = new JComboBox<>(residencyList);
        panel.add(residency, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        String[] sexList = { "Male", "Female" };
        JComboBox<String> sex = new JComboBox<>(sexList);
        panel.add(sex, gbc);

        outerPanel.add(panel);

        return outerPanel;
    }

}
```